# NET8 Blazor completed different website rendering

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm still having issues with `Blazor` project and `NET8`. I'm creating a simple website that has a server project, a client project, and a few Blazor components. The component is an [ImageSelect](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorImageSelect) that requires adding some JavaScript in the *App.razor*. I updated the component to NET8 too.

The render of the website locally is quite what I like to see and there are no errors in the developer tools.

[image]

[image]

When I deploy the website and browse it, I get completely different results. Starting with Edge on MacOS or Windows.

Here is a screenshot of the web application on Microsoft Edge on MacOS (the same on Windows).

[image]

When I inspect the developer tools, I can see that all the CSS and JavaScript embedded in the components, are not found.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () /_content/PSC.Blazor.Template.Newzin/js/lib/pace.js:1

[image]

Using Safari, the result is more strange. This is the screenshot I get when I open the website

> There was an unhandled exception on the current request. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json'

[image]

This surprises me because in the *Program.cs* of the main project, the application has to read the *appconfig.json* related to the environment and when I deploy, the environment is *Release*. Then in the developer tools, I get those errors

[image]

I can't understand where the problem is and how I can fix it. I have created a GitHub repository with the Blazor solution but it doesn't have the dependencies because this is a quite big project. If you have to have a look at the Blazor, here you have the [source code](https://github.com/erossini/Blazor8Tmp) for a few days.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to debug your code for you.

Comment: I understand that but it is a very common problem from the previous version. There are a lot of issues with embedded resources.